# jQuery : Find nth-child of a element saved as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

```
var $slideObj = $('#slideshow .slideItem');
var num = 10;
```

I got that code and I want to find the nth-child of the "$slideObj" element. The code below works but I want to use the variable instead of finding the element again.

```
var $currentSlideObj = $('#slideshow .slideItem:nth-child(' + num + ')');
```

What I want is the following, $slideObj.nth-child(num);
I have tried the following below.

```
$slideObj.find(':nth-child('+num+')');
$slideObj.eq(num);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually already have all the "children" in your `$slideObj`.

You need to use `.filter` rather than `.find` (filter the current result set, not look deeper in the tree).

```
$slideObj.filter(':nth-child(' + num + ')');
```

Comment: Worked! Keep forgetting about the filter method.